# OpenLayers Style SLD for ship

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am trying to find an sld for a Ship. I am parsing an AIS feed and would like to make the ship different colors based on class of ship and length as well as rotate it based on the COG (course). Currently I have  an Arrow that rotates but it using a well known class. I would really prefer something that actually resembles a ship based on a polygon.

Here is the style I am using currently:

```
<PointSymbolizer> 
  <Graphic> 
    <Mark> 
      <WellKnownName>arrow</WellKnownName> 
        <Fill> 
          <CssParameter name="fill">#FF0000</CssParameter> 
        </Fill> 
        <Stroke> 
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter> 
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter> 
        </Stroke> 
      </Mark> 
      <Size>12</Size> 
      <Rotation>
        <ogc:Sub>
          <ogc:PropertyName>COG</ogc:PropertyName>  
          <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Sub>
      </Rotation>
    </Graphic> 
  </PointSymbolizer>
```

Comment: You could use `<ExternalGraphic>` to point to a graphic/image, or even use text with the [Unicode value for ship](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f6a2/index.htm). Note that if you use the latter, then you will need some font which can actually draw this symbol

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the unicode symbol but I can't show rotation for direction of travel with it and I think that an external graphic may be slow.